# terraform - how to add a conditional block from map of strings, using map keys as argument names

Tags: dynamic, terraform, block

I am trying to add a conditional block to a resource if an optional map variable has key/value pairs. If the map is not null, I want to add the argument as the key, and the value as the value.

Currently this is what i'm trying to do;

```
variable "aws_attributes" {
    type = optional(map(string))
    default = {"arg1":"val1", "arg2":"val2"}
}

dynamic "aws_attributes" {
    for_each = { for key, value in var.aws_attributes: key => value }
    content {
       key = value
    }
}
```

The problem I get is: `An argument named "key" is not expected here.` which seems to indicate I have an issue with interpolation not happening.

I tried this too:

```
dynamic "aws_attributes" {
    for_each = var.aws_attributes
    content {
      key = value
      }
}
```

and get

```
Error: Unsupported argument

  on modules/dlt_jobs/main.tf line 37, in resource "databricks_pipeline" "this":
  37:                      key = value

An argument named "key" is not expected here.
```

If the map is empty the "aws_attributes" block should not be created at all, and if its not empty it should be populated with key/values from the map variable (aws_attributes).

Just for good measure, here is the entire resource block.

```
resource "databricks_pipeline" "this" {

    name = var.dlt_jobs.task_name
    storage = var.dlt_jobs.storage_location

    dynamic "library" {
        for_each = var.dlt_jobs.notebook_libraries
        content {
            notebook {
                path = "${local.user_home}${library.value}"
            }
        }
    }
    configuration = {
        input = var.dlt_jobs.configuration.input
        "pipelines.UI.enablePartialGraphUpdate" = var.dlt_jobs.configuration.pipeline_refresh
    }

    dynamic "cluster" {
        for_each = var.dlt_jobs.cluster != null ? var.dlt_jobs.cluster : []
        content {
            label = "default"
            
            spark_conf = var.spark_conf
            
            dynamic "aws_attributes" {
               for_each = var.aws_attributes
                content {
                     key = value
               }
            }
            autoscale  {
                min_workers = 1
                max_workers = 5
                mode = "ENHANCED"
            }
            custom_tags = {
                cluster_type = "job_cluster"
            }
        }
    }
    continuous = var.dlt_jobs.continous
    photon = var.dlt_jobs.photon
    target = var.dlt_jobs.target_database
    edition = var.dlt_jobs.edition
    channel = var.dlt_jobs.channel
}
```

Anyone got any ideas please?

Comment: What is the full error message showing exact line where the error occurs?

Comment: It probably needs to be `each.key = each.value` instead of `key = value`.

Comment: ahh - OK - So I hadn't caught the previous error. Updated the question, as it might be i'm declaring the block incorrectly?

Comment: Your `for` expression is mapping the input to the return exactly one-to-one. It is completely equivalent to `for_each = var.aws_attributes`. Why not use that instead?

Comment: I did try that too. updated the question to show how I tried that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case i would recommend to just create the code like this, as the number of optional attributes is small.

Terraform provider should ignore values set to `null` an should default to the internal provider default in this case. (I do not know the databricks provider well enough)

The code would look like this.

```
dynamic "aws_attributes" {
  for_each = [var.aws_attributes]

  content {
    zone_id                = aws_attributes.value.zone_id
    availability           = try(aws_attributes.value.availability, null)
    first_on_demand        = try(aws_attributes.value.first_on_demand, null)
    spot_bid_price_percent = try(aws_attributes.value.spot_bid_price_percent, null)
    instance_profile_arn   = try(aws_attributes.value.instance_profile_arn, null)
    ebs_volume_type        = try(aws_attributes.value.ebs_volume_type, null)
    ebs_volume_count       = try(aws_attributes.value.ebs_volume_count, null)
    ebs_volume_size        = try(aws_attributes.value.ebs_volume_size, null)
  }
}
```

The loop could be improved to also allow not generating the block if it is `null`:

`for_each = var.aws_attributes != null ? [var.aws_attributes] : []`

or

`for_each = length(var.aws_attributes) > 0 ? [var.aws_attributes] : []`

The same behavior could be achieved using the `lookup()` function instead of `try()`.

---

For more dynamic generation of Terraform Code in general, you can also use tooling like [Terramate](https://github.com/mineiros-io/terramate) that offers ways to achieve very flexible dynamic generation but follows a different data model to set values:

```
globals {
  aws_attributes = { zone_id = "us-west-2a", availability = "SPOT" }
}

generate_hcl "main.tf" {
  content {
    # other surrounding code ...

    tm_dynamic "aws_attributes" {
      # only generate block if there are keys
      condition = tm_length(global.aws_attributes) > 0

      # dynamically fill the block with all key/value pairs
      attributes = global.aws_attributes
    }

    # other code 

  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this great explanation. I have been able to resolve the issue with this great write up!